# Post Method with Chai (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, chai

I am having trouble making my unit test pass and I think it is because it is posting using the wrong type of data. My route:

```
let upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

router.route('/')
    .post(upload.any('image'), function (req, res, next) {
        let memory = new Memory();
        if (req.files.length === 0) {
          Object.assign(memory, req.body);
        } else {
          Object.assign(memory, req.body, {'image': req.file.secure_url});
        }

        memory.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'Memory Created', memory});
        });
    })
```

As you can see my route uses `multer` which accepts `form-data` as input. However, in my `Chai test`:

```
it('it should not post an item without a location field', (done) => {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('description', "First time we met");
      formData.append('image','n/a');

        chai.request(server)
            .post('/api/memory')
            .set('Accept', 'application/form-data')
            .send(formData)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.body.should.be.a('object');
                res.body.should.have.property('errors');
                res.body.errors.should.have.property('location');
                res.body.errors.location.should.have.property('kind').eql('required');
                done();
            });
```

I am using Chai's `send` method but this test just freezes and gives me no response. So I tried using `postman` and if I send data using `x-www-form-urlencoded` it feezes but if I send data using `form-data` it works fine. So I suspect I am sending data in `x-www-form-urlencded` using Chai. How do I fix this? (Note: I tried using `.set('Accept', 'application/form-data')`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.field()`

```
describe('/POST item', () => {
    it('it should not post an item without a location field', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/api/memory')
            .set('Accept', 'application/form-data')
            .field('description', "First time we met")
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.body.should.be.a('object');
                res.body.should.have.property('errors');
                res.body.errors.should.have.property('location');
                res.body.errors.location.should.have.property('kind').eql('required');
                done();
            });
    });
```